# Transform backtrace to string during catch_unwind

Tags: rust, error-handling, backtrace

I am writing a cross-platform (Linux/iOS/Android) library in Rust. In case my library panics I want the application to continue working as normal and not crash. In order to do that, I am using [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/controlling-panics-with-std-panic.html); its result contains panic information and doesn't contain enough information about the source of the problem, here is a piece of code explaining what I am doing:

```rust
fn calculate(json: &str) -> String {
    unimplemented!()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn rust_calculation(json: &str) -> String {
    let r = std::panic::catch_unwind(||{
        // rust calculation
        let calc: String = calculate(json).into();
        calc
    });
    let r_str = match r {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => {
            let panic_information = match e.downcast::<String>() {
                Ok(v) => *v,
                _ => "Unknown Source of Error".to_owned()
            };
            panic_information
        }
    };
    return r_str;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", rust_calculation("test"));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3784a082fda2ea092e40af0c6262dd2d)

In case an error occurs, the message returned is not sufficient, and sometimes, it only contains the message

> Unknown Source of Error

I want to send the backtrace to the calling source so that it can log it and then we can debug the Rust library afterwards. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> some times it countains the message:
>
> > Unknown Source of Error

This is probably because `e` may not only be a `String`, but also a `&str` (well, it can basically be any type, but those two are the most common, you can only get other types when using [`panic_any()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.panic_any.html)). When calling `panic!()` inside `catch_unwind()`, you only get a `String` if you are `panic!`'ing with arguments, otherwise, the panic message is a `&str` (as there is no need for allocating a `String`).

> I want to send the backtrace to the calling source so that he can log it and then we can debug the rust library afterwards, how can I do that ?

## Solution on nightly Rust

On nightly Rust, you can generate a backtrace inside a panic handler via `std::backtrace::Backtrace`:

```rust
#![feature(backtrace)]
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

// on panic, save the backtrace here (as string)
lazy_static! {
    static ref BACKTRACE: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn rust_calculation(json: &str) -> String {
    let r = std::panic::catch_unwind(||{
        panic!("Panic");
    });
    let r_str = match r {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => {
            let panic_information = match e.downcast::<String>() {
                Ok(v) => *v,
                Err(e) => match e.downcast::<&str>() {
                    Ok(v) => v.to_string(),
                    _ => "Unknown Source of Error".to_owned()
                }
            };
            format!("{}\nBacktrace:\n{}", panic_information, BACKTRACE.lock().unwrap().take().unwrap_or("<Backtrace not found>".to_string()))
        }
    };
    return r_str;
}

fn panic_hook(_: &std::panic::PanicInfo) {
    *BACKTRACE.lock().unwrap() = Some(std::backtrace::Backtrace::force_capture().to_string());
}

fn main() {
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(panic_hook));
    println!("{}", rust_calculation(""));
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=553d56c85662e1b670696850716b1d11)

Output:

```
Panic
Backtrace:
   0: playground::panic_hook
             at ./src/main.rs:32:39
   1: core::ops::function::Fn::call
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:70:5
   2: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:626:17
   3: std::panicking::begin_panic::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:542:9
   4: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:141:18
   5: std::panicking::begin_panic
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:541:12
   6: playground::rust_calculation::{{closure}}
             at ./src/main.rs:13:9
   7: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:401:40
   8: __rust_try
   9: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:365:19
  10: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panic.rs:434:14
  11: rust_calculation
             at ./src/main.rs:12:13
  12: playground::main
             at ./src/main.rs:37:20
  13: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
  14: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:125:18
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/rt.rs:63:18
  16: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
  17: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:401:40
  18: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:365:19
  19: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panic.rs:434:14
  20: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/rt.rs:45:48
  21: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:401:40
  22: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panicking.rs:365:19
  23: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/panic.rs:434:14
  24: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/rt.rs:45:20
  25: std::rt::lang_start
             at /rustc/2faabf579323f5252329264cc53ba9ff803429a3/library/std/src/rt.rs:62:5
  26: main
  27: __libc_start_main
  28: _start
```

Please note that this backtrace contains a few additional frames after the call to `panic!` that are due to Rust's internal panic handling code.

## Solution with dependencies

If you are not on nightly Rust, but are willing to use additional dependencies, you can do the same with the [`backtrace` crate](https://docs.rs/backtrace/latest) (thanks to @BashirAbdelwahed for calling my attention to this):

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

// on panic, save the backtrace here (as string)
lazy_static! {
    static ref BACKTRACE: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn rust_calculation(json: &str) -> String {
    let r = std::panic::catch_unwind(||{
        panic!("Panic");
    });
    let r_str = match r {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => {
            let panic_information = match e.downcast::<String>() {
                Ok(v) => *v,
                Err(e) => match e.downcast::<&str>() {
                    Ok(v) => v.to_string(),
                    _ => "Unknown Source of Error".to_owned()
                }
            };
            format!("{}\nBacktrace:\n{}", panic_information, BACKTRACE.lock().unwrap().take().unwrap_or("<Backtrace not found>".to_string()))
        }
    };
    return r_str;
}

fn panic_hook(_: &std::panic::PanicInfo) {
    *BACKTRACE.lock().unwrap() = Some(format!("{:?}", backtrace::Backtrace::new()));
}

fn main() {
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(panic_hook));
    println!("{}", rust_calculation(""));
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68f474956d3c97f1d827f61a63d7caae)

Output:

```
Panic
Backtrace:
   0: playground::panic_hook
             at src/main.rs:31:55
   1: core::ops::function::Fn::call
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:70:5
   2: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:595:17
   3: std::panicking::begin_panic::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:520:9
   4: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:141:18
   5: std::panicking::begin_panic
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:519:12
   6: playground::rust_calculation::{{closure}}
             at src/main.rs:12:9
   7: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:379:40
   8: __rust_try
   9: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:343:19
  10: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panic.rs:431:14
  11: rust_calculation
             at src/main.rs:11:13
  12: playground::main
             at src/main.rs:36:20
  13: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
  14: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:125:18
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/rt.rs:49:18
  16: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
      std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:379:40
      std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:343:19
      std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/panic.rs:431:14
      std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/rt.rs:34:21
  17: std::rt::lang_start
             at /rustc/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/rt.rs:48:5
  18: main
  19: __libc_start_main
  20: _start
```

Comment: But is it a good idea to include in the production binary ? how about in release mode ?

Comment: Good to know: Backtrace is not nightly anymore!